# Step in proof about UMVU estimator

Tags: statistics

> Let $V$ be a statistic that is sufficient and complete, and let
>   $T=T(V)$ be an unbiased estimator for $g(\theta)$, which only depends
>   on $V$. Then $T$ is a UMVU estimator for $g(\theta)$.

My book proves this as follows:

According to Rao-Blackwall, there exists an unbiased estimator $S^*=S^*(V)$ with $\operatorname{var} S^*\leq \operatorname{var} S$. Now $S^*-T$ is a statistic that only depends on $V$ with $E_\theta(S^*-T)=E_\theta S^*- E_\theta T=0$ for all $\theta$, because both estimators are unbiased.

The proof continues, but I don’t understand why we can treat $E_\theta$ linearly - because how do we know that $S^*$ and $T$ are independent?

Comment: The fact that expectation is linear does not require independence! It holds for the sum of any finite number of arbitrary random variables, as long as each of them has finite expectation.

Comment: Oh, I think I confused it with the rule for variance. Thanks!